# Error accessing url using ILIKE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to access the page according to the specified url but I am getting the following error

> SQLite3::SQLException: near "ILIKE": syntax error: SELECT  "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE ('testimonials.html' ILIKE path || '%' AND path <> '') LIMIT 1

I am trying something like this

```
@page = Page.where("'#{params[:url]}' ILIKE path || '%' AND path <> ''").first
```

any suggestions ??

Comment: What is the requirement?

Comment: Hey salil I am trying to access the page provided in the url .I am trying to use one query for all the pages acccording to there name.

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

By the very little i got your question i think you want something like following

```
@page = Page.where("(path LIKE '#{params[:url]}' OR path = '%') AND path != ''").first
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   @page = Page.where("(path LIKE ? OR path = '%') AND path != ''",params[:url]).first
```